# Visual Studio 2010 signed project template

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, templates

I am creating a multi-project template for Visual Studio 2010, each of the projects in the template need to have an strong name key assigned. Originally I created a strong name key for each project and then created the templates. However, when using the templates the strong name key doesn't change, which kind of defeats the purpose of having it signed.

Is there a way (short of implementing template wizards on each class that executes the sn.exe file and modifyies the project xml to include this newly generated snk) to get the projects to generate a new snk each time?